# Output REAL 4 value in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, masm32

I'm creating an assembly program (intel 8086 masm32)which contains some simple division. And everything was working until the division produced a float.

Because when you load the float to the eax register it just returns a massive number.

To try and solve the problem i found out about FUP and used the REAL 4 to store the float and it works.
My question is how can I output the float REAL 4 value to the console using the WriteConsoleA WindowsAPI?
Or maybe there is a different way to deal with floats in this situation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to convert to text yourself, or use the C library if available.

Comment: If you don't need a floating point result you could use the integer division instructions DIV and IDIV instead, as integers are easier to convert into text.

Comment: @Jester Thanks, C library isn't really an option, I'll try to convert it text..Tho from my understanding that isn't as easy as it sounds...

Answer (score 0):

As luck would have it I not long ago hand wrote some string to/from decimal routines using only basic instructions.

They're already commented out for another group that I am helping, but you may also find them useful.

It's all simple stuff i.e. the "strlen" proc might often be faster with scasb etc.. etc., but they are basically a teaching aid for beginners, but being ASM they are of course, easily fast enough for any task involving human interaction. Possibly faster than wsprintf et.al. as they are only handling a single case (decimal).

They're only written for whole numbers, however as you are only looking to output a decimal string, it should be fairly simple to output the integer part followed by an 02Eh then multiply the fractional part by 10^SignificantPlaces and write that out also.

Have fun =D

Oh BTW: for many division jobs where I need a bit of precision for calculations, but the final results end up being integers, then as long as the values I'm working with aren't too large, I find it conveniant to just shl xxx,8 or shl xxx,16 everything then div and whatever else until I get a result then just shr xxx,whatever everything and keep on trucking ;)

Possibly not appropriate for your current project, but often a useful method.

```
.data?
  decbuf db 32 dup(?)

.code

;  DECIMAL to/from STRING routines
;        Lambchops 2/2017
;       ( a boy from AUS )


strlen proc saddr:DWORD ; 
; return length of string at saddr
  mov eax,saddr
  dec eax
  @@:
    inc eax
    cmp byte ptr [eax], 0
    jnz @B
  sub eax,saddr
  ret
strlen endp

mul10 proc val:DWORD,expo:DWORD
; multiply val x10 expo times
  push ebx
  push ecx

  mov eax,val
  mov ecx,expo
  test ecx,ecx
  jz mul10out

    @@:
      lea ebx,[eax*2]
      lea eax,[ebx+eax*8]   ; x2 + x8 = x10
    loop @B

  mul10out:
  pop ecx
  pop ebx
  ret
mul10 endp

isDecChar proc cchar:DWORD
  ; is the low byte of cchar '0'->'9'?
  ; zf=true
  push eax
  mov eax,cchar
  mov ah,1
  cmp al,'0'
  jb @F
    cmp al,'9'
    ja @F
      xor eax,eax
  @@:
  test eax,eax
  pop eax
  ret
isDecChar endp


getDecimal proc saddr:DWORD
; get the integer value of the unsigned decimal string at address saddr
;
; ignores any char that is not a decimal digit ** including '.' **
;----------------------------------------------------------------------
LOCAL retval
  pushad

  ; zero return value
  mov retval,0

  ; get src address
  mov esi,saddr

  ; get string length
  push esi
  call strlen

  ; zero length string?
  test eax,eax
  jz getdecout

  ; add the length to the buffer address
  add esi,eax

  ; esi points to zero terminator so dec
  dec esi

  ; set loop counter to string length
  mov ecx,eax

  ; zero the column number
  xor ebx,ebx

  @@:
    xor edx,edx
    ; get char in dl
    mov dl,[esi]
    dec esi

    ; is the char a decimal digit?
    push edx
    call isDecChar
    ; skip anything else
    jnz skipBadChar

      ; char '0'=48 so subtract this to get that char's value
      sub edx,48

      ; multiply by 10^column number
      push ebx
      push edx
      call mul10

      ; add to return value
      add retval,eax

      ; inc the column number
      inc ebx

    skipBadChar:
  loop @B

  getdecout:
  popad
  mov eax,retval
  ret
getDecimal endp

strDecimal proc daddr:DWORD,val:DWORD
;--------------------------------------------------------
; write unsigned integer val as a decimal string at daddr
;--------------------------------------------------------
  pushad
  mov edi,OFFSET decbuf
  mov ebx,10
  mov eax,val

  ; generate the string
  ;(backwards in decbuf)
  @@:
    ; must clear edx before using div
    xor edx,edx

    ; "div" divides eax by the operand (here ebx=10)
    ; and leaves the remainder in edx, so the remainder
    ; becomes our next digit value, and we continue
    ; until eax=0
    div ebx

    ; add '0' to the remainder to convert
    ; it to an ASCII char
    add dl,48

    ; write the char to the buffer
    mov [edi],dl

    ; inc the buffer ptr
    inc edi

    ; finished?
    test eax,eax
  jnz @B

  ;append a zero terminator
  mov BYTE ptr[edi],0

  ; reverse the string and copy to daddr
  ; (you can work this out, surely ;)
  push OFFSET decbuf
  call strlen

  mov ecx,eax
  add eax,OFFSET decbuf
  mov edi,daddr
  @@:
    dec eax
    mov dl,[eax]
    mov [edi],dl
    inc edi
  loop @B
  mov BYTE ptr[edi],0
  popad
  ret
strDecimal endp

;   Please Note:
;
;   These routines have not been exhaustively tested under all
;   conditions but appeared to function correctly for the task
;   they were written for ( punting smallish integers to and 
;   from a bunch of EditText boxes ).
```